# Responsive image on top of responsive image CSS

Tags: css, image, responsive-design

I've got a logo on my website that i'm trying to make stay in the middle and be responsive. I've tried tons of CSS code from "magin-left:auto;..." to "top:30..." but the logo wont get smaller and stay in the middle. I was wondering if anyone could help me. Heres my website -- http://www.mediadude.co.uk -- The logo is the big mediadude sign in the middle, Try resizing the browser and you can see that it doesn't stay in the middle and get smaller.

Thanks for you time.
Hantoo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set `max-width` to the image but not to the `h1` tag.

```
h1#LogoMain {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Also you have a media query giving `body` `padding: 20`

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    body {
        padding-top: 0;
        padding-right: 20px;
        padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Change the above values to `0` for an edge to edge look on your header etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had to add a few more media queries to make it stay at the top because when I resized the tab it would move down, But i think thats to do with how big the image is. Should of put some extra space on the sides. Thanks anyway it really helped me get on track :)

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/TJF8k/1/

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <div class="imgwrap">
    <img class="image" src="//placehold.it/400x150">
  </div>
</div>
```

For the CSS, you'll need to adjust the negative `margin-bottom` on `.floater` based on the dimensions of your image.

```
.header {
  background-color: teal;
  height: 300px;
}

.floater {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -10%;
}

.imgwrap {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.image {
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```